# How to list a folder using FluentFTP

Tags: c#, ftp, fluentftp

I am implementing FluentFTP in my application but I cannot list the contents of a folder on the FTP server.
When I use an ftp application like FileZilla I can clearly see that in my user directory there are 2 folders :

[image]

The Out folder contains some files, but when I retrieve a listing using FluentFTP I always get these 2 folders, not the contents of the Out folder.

This is the code I am using

```
FtpClient client = new FtpClient();
client.Host = _ftpDefinition.Host;
client.Port = _ftpDefinition.Port;
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_ftpDefinition.UserName, _ftpDefinition.PassWord);
client.Connect();

foreach (FtpListItem item in ftpClient.GetListing(remoteDir))
{
    if (item.Type == FtpFileSystemObjectType.File)
    {
         _remoteFiles.Add(item.Name); // add the filename to a List<string>
    }
}
```

I tried these combinations for the variable remoteDir :

```
Out
/Out
Out/
/Out/
```

none of them is working, the GetListing always retuns the 2 folders in stead of the contents of the Out folder.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Can you not change directory to outfolder?

Comment: Good idea, how can I do this with FluentFTP ?

Comment: otherwise when you do _remoteFiles.Add .. chances are it puts it in your current directory not where you wanted..

Comment: Sounds like a FluentFTP bug. I've [opened an issue](https://github.com/robinrodricks/FluentFTP/issues/263).

Comment: By the way, Guido, if you can provide more info [on the bug report](https://github.com/robinrodricks/FluentFTP/issues/263), I'm sure Robin would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

According to [their docs](https://github.com/hgupta9/FluentFTP)

You should be able to use

GetWorkingDirectory() - Gets the full path of the current working directory.

SetWorkingDirectory() - Sets the full path of the current working directory.

Such as

`FtpClient.SetWorkingDirectory("/Out");`

Comment: That seems to be working, can you think of any reason why the GetListing() does not works with the same /Out ?

Comment: Never used fluentftp ever :p sorry. it maybe its case sensitive and despite showing with caps, its lower case.. it would be one of those things Id want to see in raw ftp client (not filezilla) and the server end to tell you maybe more why (the server would have logs of whats sent)

Comment: For some reason this solution stopped working. When I do GetWorkingDirectory after the SetWorkingDirectory it returns /Out like it did before, but for some reason the GetListing() now always retuns nothing even when there are files there. I am starting to think that FluentFTP is not that good after all and that I need to start looking for another library again

Comment: Does sound dodgy.  Is listing allowed in the out folder? Are there maybe settings like passive ftp that filezilla turns on by default you have not?

Comment: I switched to another library, edtFTPFree and this one works like a charm right from the beginning. Thanks for you time and effort